# How to find users who made an order in any year then didn't make one the year after

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table scheme looks like this

```
id | user_id | price | date
1235085 | 429009 | 1301.3 | 2016-01-01
1235016 | 1106100 | 2343.6 | 2016-01-01
1235007 | 707164 | 980.7 | 2016-01-01
```

there are 20 million records.

I have to find users which are made some orders in any year, but didn't the following year.

I tried use this query

```
select user_id
from orders o1
where not exists (select user_id from orders o2
                  where extract(year from o2.date) + 1 > extract(year from o1.date))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What happens if they ordered after two years?

Comment: Do you want customers with only 2019 orders to be returned?

Comment: No. there are some years. from 2016 to 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EXCEPT:

```
select distinct user_id from orders
except
select distinct user_id 
from orders o1
where exists(
  select 1 
  from orders o2 
  where o2.user_id = o1.user_id 
  and extract(year from o2.date) + 1 = extract(year from o1.date)
)
```

Comment: I think it is wrong query because it is returns users with ID = 1, but he made orders 2 years in a row

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select user_id, yyyy
from (select user_id, date_trunc('year', date) as yyyy,
             lead(date_trunc('year', date)) over (partition by user_id order by date_trunc('year', date)) as next_year
      from t
      group by user_id, yyyy
     ) u
where next_year <> yyyy + interval '1 year' or next_year is null;
```

This assumes that you actually want the year as well.  If not, use `select distinct user_id`.

You might also want to add the condition `yyyy <> date_trunc(now())` so you don't get users who made their first purchase this year.  Without this condition, I think you will return all users, because every user has a "last purchase" with no purchases the following year.

EDIT:

Interestingly, you can do this with `lead()` as well:

```
select user_id, date
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by user_id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where (next_date is null or
       extract(year from next_date) <> extract(year from date) + 1
      ) and
      date < date_trunc('year', now());
```

Because `lead()` orders the values, this should return at most one value for a given year, even when there are multiple orders in a year.

Comment: Thanks for big answer, but it is incorrect. It returns a lot of users which are bought goods in 2016 and 2017 (or 2017 and 2018)

Comment: @Viktor . . . The first query should have returned an error, because the `order by` was missing for the `lead()`.  I'm surprised that Postgres accepted it.  In any case, with the `order by` it should work.